# Burninate the [unresolved] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I'm struggling to see any value in having an [unresolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unresolved) tag:

- It has no followers
- There is no tag wiki
- There are only 152 tagged questions at the time of writing
- There are no experts in the tag
- There are no questions where "unresolved" is the *only* tag
- The tag by itself is too broad (could be an unresolved dependency, compilation error, variable, etc...)

I'd also argue that it's not possible to be an expert in "unresolved". Can we/should we burninate this tag?

Comment: It appears to be an accidentally-created tag, caused by people typing sentences into the tags field. It serves no legitimate purpose that I can see, either.

Comment: It looks like there should be a few tags that are more specific to replace this one.

Comment: Maybe we should use it to categorize questions probably, as we have both: [tag:done] and [tag:unresolved] ;-)

Comment: @Deduplicator - we already have Unanswered.

Comment: @erno: are you trolling me, or did you just not see the smiley? Anyway, mostly wanted to name the equally useful companion-tag.

Comment: I am compelled to agree solely on the fact that you are using invoking the spirit of Trogdor. On the second thought, I find your reasons very strong and compelling on their own merits.

Comment: @Deduplicator - Sorry, I missed the smiley (probably due to the dash after it) I don't troll (intentionally).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This tag says nothing about the question. What exactly is unresolved? Also, how can anyone be an expert in 'unresolved'? The whole point of tags is that experts in the area of the question can find the question easier.

Let it burn.

Comment: And now it's been resolved.